# How to fix, "The requested URL /login was not found on this server" issue on the server end when trying to load a laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, server, redhat

I am setting up my Laravel project on a redhat server. When I load the url, I keep getting greeted with this, "`The requested URL /login was not found on this server`". However, when I change my **httpd.conf** to direct my index to `DirectoryIndex xxx/public/phpinfo.php`, it can load the phpinfo. But when I direct it to my index.php as such; `DirectoryIndex xxx/public/index.php`, it returns the above error.

**Httpd.conf settings**;

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/xxx/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex xxx/public/index.php
</IfModule>
```

**.htaccess file**;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

So I really do not know what I'm doing wrong here, and have been through a lot of threads, but can't get this fixed. At this point, any help would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try `yourdomain.com/index.php/login`?

Comment: hey @PrafullaKumarSahu . It does not work. I've put my phpinfo.php inside the public folder as well, and when i key in, mydomain.com/phpinfo.php it does not open it. but when i direct it to my phpinfo.php in the httpd.conf it works.

Comment: then your document root is not set properly.

Comment: where would i set this? @PrafullaKumarSahu

Comment: In your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` set  document root.

Comment: ohh, it works now, but i get another error, "The stream or file "/var/www/html/jci-backend/storage/logs/laravel-2019-05-02.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied" . But i think i can fix this. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf set

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/yourproject/public
```

and for

> The stream or file
>   "/var/www/html/jci-backend/storage/logs/laravel-2019-05-02.log" could
>   not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied"

On ubuntu

change permission using `sudo chmod 775 -R /var/www/html/jci-backend/storage/logs/laravel-2019-05-02.log`

On redhat you can try

```
sudo chmod o+w /var/www/html/jci-backend/storage/logs/laravel-2019-05-02.log
```

Comment: hey thanks for this. However my server is running on redhat, the sudo chmod command wont work, as its a different handler.

Comment: @UdhayanNair I have updated my answer, can you try that?

Comment: hey, so ive tried that command line, and the weirdest thing happened, it says that it cannot access '/var/www/html/jci-backend/storage/logs/laravel-2019-05-02.log' as theres's no such directory or file. and when i went in tocheck, there was no such log. :/

Comment: @UdhayanNair it depends on where you are and from current location what is the relative path of file, for which you are changing the permission.

Comment: @UdhayanNair by the way, it is a different question and you can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/how-to-fix-error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened/44647615

Comment: i've followed the steps accordingly, but i still get the error.

Comment: "The stream or file "/var/www/html/jci-backend/storage/logs/laravel-2019-05-02.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied" the same error

Comment: @UdhayanNair  then change the permissions for storage/logs folder and check again and let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: nope, just tried chmod 775 -R storage/logs, it didnt work. i executed teh same command for storage, and my jci-backend folder as well. didnt work..

Comment: managed to get it to work by following this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306315/laravel-5-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened-permission-denied/36658378

Comment: but now i get this. "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxi.com/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://xxi.com/css/bootstrap.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

Comment: @UdhayanNair  check if all your css and js are loading with either http or https and not both.

Comment: its loading via http. damn. in my code, i set the `href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"` i jsut need to set itso that asset caters for http and https right?

Comment: @UdhayanNair try it.

Comment: @UdhayanNair  if your domain has https use https or make all http and it should work fine.